# Why i'm losing the ability to scroll in mobile when i add css media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

Is there something wrong with my styles or media query? When im in my phone i lose the ability to scroll down.  here is my only media query

```
@media (max-width: 568px) {
    header {
        padding: 1em 0;
        position: fixed;
        .logo {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .main-nav {
            display: none;
         }
         #burger-icon {
            width: 27px;
            display: block;
         }
    }
    #section1 {
        height: 500px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #section2 {
        .col-1 {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .col-2 {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-top: 20px;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need more context. Can you link the site?

Comment: Try @media screen and (max-width: 568px)

Comment: http://dynamic-thurston.com/ I tried that but didnt work  here is the link of the site.

Comment: There's something wrong with the overflow of your containers. In Firefox, I have to scrollbars on the side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
header {
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: fixed;
    .logo {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .main-nav {
        display: none;
     }
     #burger-icon {
        width: 27px;
        display: block;
     }
}
#section1 {
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
#section2 {
    .col-1 {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was the skrollr declaration on my script it was my own mistake thankyou for all the help i think the skrollr.js has issue with mobile.